# Copy unique values from one column to another R

Tags: r

I have recently started using R and although I have a manual for it I keep on finding that the functions that I need can't be found there. Here is a problem I stumbled upon.

MY data looks something like this:

```
col1    col2    col3
Alex    NA  URL
Mike    URL NA
John    URL URL
Peter   NA  NA
James   NA  URL
```

Col1 will always be a unique categorical value. Col2 represents the source where these people are coming from, to my website (URL means that there is an entire URL in there , could http.www.facebook.com). NA means that the user came to my website viral. Col3 represents the referal (another indication of where the user came from).

What I need to do is to transfer or copy data from col3 into col2, based on the following condition: IF in col 3 I have an URL and in col2 I have NA, then the cell with the URL from col3 I need it copyied to col2. If col3 and col2, both have URL then I don't want anything to happen there. If col 3 has NA and col2 has URL, again I don't want anything to change. Here is the desired output

```
col1    col2                    col3   
Alex    URL(copied from col3)   URL
Mike    URL(kept this URL)      NA
John    URL(kept this URL)      URL
Peter   NA(Kept NA)             NA
James   URL(copied from col3)   URL
```

SO, Alex and James got the URL from col3 , John and Mike kept their initial URL that were in col2 and Peter kept his NA.

Now, I have looked everywhere , even on this website and was unable to find anything about copying data from one column to another using "IF" conditions. The only thing I found was how to copy an entire column from one dataframe to another by using the "merge" function, but apart from that nothing else.

Does a function exist that could acomplish this?

Comment: You forgot to add the language tag [r], this will make it veeeery unlikely someone will answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is not reproducible, so I'll have to create some of my own:

```
dat = data.frame(name = sample(c("John", "James", "Peter"), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
                 source = sprintf("http://www.%s.com", sample(LETTERS, size = 10)),
                 referal = sprintf("http://www.%s.com", sample(LETTERS, size = 10)))
# Introduce some NA's
dat[c(1,3,9), "source"] <- NA
dat[c(2,7), "referal"] <- NA
> dat
    name           source          referal
1   John             <NA> http://www.W.com                          
2  James http://www.M.com             <NA>                          
3   John             <NA> http://www.Z.com                          
4  Peter http://www.J.com http://www.L.com                          
5  Peter http://www.L.com http://www.H.com                          
6  Peter http://www.T.com http://www.U.com                          
7  James http://www.E.com             <NA>                          
8  Peter http://www.K.com http://www.K.com                          
9  Peter             <NA> http://www.R.com                          
10 James http://www.Z.com http://www.N.com
```

The function you are looking for is called `ifelse`:

```
dat = within(dat, { 
      source = as.character(source)
      referal = as.character(referal)
      source = ifelse(is.na(source), referal, source) 
    } )
> dat
    name           source          referal
1   John http://www.W.com http://www.W.com                          
2  James http://www.M.com             <NA>                          
3   John http://www.Z.com http://www.Z.com                          
4  Peter http://www.J.com http://www.L.com                          
5  Peter http://www.L.com http://www.H.com                          
6  Peter http://www.T.com http://www.U.com                          
7  James http://www.E.com             <NA>                          
8  Peter http://www.K.com http://www.K.com                          
9  Peter http://www.R.com http://www.R.com                          
10 James http://www.Z.com http://www.N.com
```

Comment: Hi Paul. Thank you first of all for telling me about tagging the R language, will bare that in mind from now on :). I have tried your method and it did not seem to work for me. For some reason , it replaced the values in the Source column with random numbers. How can I take a screen grab of the R output like you did , so I can show you this? David

Comment: The problem is probably that the column `source` in your case is a `factor`. Please transform it to a `character` column using `as.character`. I edited this into my answer.

Comment: That solved it. Thank you very much again for your help, I much apreciate it. And if you like challenges I might have another one for you soon. :)) All the best David Rogers. PS: it's about breaking down the URL's into smaller bits and getting only a specific piece of information from it, sort of like a "text to columns" in excel. I will write write the complete example soon.

Comment: If you think this answered your question, please press the green tickmark. This shows everyone the question has been asnwered.